# Regex matching multiple lines multiple times

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
Name: John Doe

Age: 23

Primary Language: English

Description: This is a multiline
description field that I want 
to capture

Country: Canada
```

That's not the actual data, but you can see what I'm trying to do. I want to use regex to get an array of the "key" fields (Name, Age, Primary Language, Description, Country) and their values.

I'm using PHP.

My current attempt is this, but it doesn't work:

```
preg_match( '/^(.*?\:) (.*?)(\n.*?\:)/ism', $text, $matches );
```

Comment: There is a \n but your modifiers say that every newline is a new string. And the . also matches \n

Comment: I assume the data is populated by a user. Is the data coming from a `$_POST` or out of a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution: http://rubular.com/r/uDgXcIvhac.

```
    \s*([^:]+?)\s*:\s*(.*(?:\s*(?!.*:).*)*)\s*
```

Note that I've used a negative lookahead assertion, `(?!.*:)`.  This is the only way you can check that the next line *doesn't* look like a new field, and at the same time continue where you left off.  (This is why lookaheads and lookbehinds are known as *zero-width* assertions.)

EDIT: Removed bit about arbitrary-width lookaheads; I was mistaken.  The above solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Would PHP's strtok help you? You could use it with ":" as the delimeter/token and trim leading and trailing spaces to remove the unwanted new lines.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php