# Regex Help - Capture value even if it goes to the next line

Tags: php, regex, scripting

I'm trying to capture particular values for a custom alarm monitoring text and email alert system and have been mildly successful. However, sometimes the data being fed to my engine can be a little sporadic so my current regex system fails.

For instance, here is an example of what I receive in an email and formatting it can get:

**Example:**

```
CS#: A192255
Site Name: Home Alarm
Date and Time: Oct  1 2012  7:37AM                                       =
   User #: 17
User Name: User# 17                                               Event: =
CEE400 - OPEN                                               Zone: E401 - =
Caller_ID:  =0A=
=0D
```

I used to read the file line by line and it worked great but then some items would be on the same line and it blew me up. Now I read the entire email file and search for the items I'm interested in.

I'm using the following REGEX items to find the pertinent objects. Some use the : seperator but as you can see by EVENT the value ends up being on the next line which screwballs my normal regex.

**REGEX**

```
>/CS#:(.*?)A[0-9]{6}/
/Site Name:(.*?)[a-zA-Z0-9\'\"\-\_\[\]\s]{0,30}[\r\n]/
/Date and Time:(.*?)[a-zA-Z]{3}(.*?)[0-9]{1,2}(.*?)[0-9]{4}(.*?)[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}/
/CEE[0-9]{3}|CIE[0-9]{3}/ - For the EVENT: line
/Zone:(.*?)[0-9]{1,3}[a-zA-Z0-9\s\'\"\-\_\[\]\s]{0,50}+/
"/User #:(.*?)[0-9]{1,3}/
```

On this particular problem, I have the SITE NAME item looking for a string of characters, up to 30 or until it hits a newline. That seemed to be working, then I received the following email and it captured up to the '=20' character.

**Example 2**

```
CS#: A197789
Site Name: Made up name (F/A)
111E 1st Street=20
Somewhere, AZ 99999
Date and Time: Oct  1 2012  9:14AM
Event: CEE602 - TIMER TEST
Zone: E602 -  Caller_ID: timer test
Site Phone 1: 
Site Phone 2:=20
System Description: NX 8 Caddx LF=0A=
=0D
```

If anyone can view my simple minded regex items and help me find a better solution I would be so appreciative!

Comment: I think I may have answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552571/regex-matching-multiple-lines-multiple-times/10554359#10554359.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/bnalQZlNZt), using your example, of the aforementioned solution:

```
\s*([^:]+?)\s*:\s*(.*(?:\s*(?!.*:).*)*)\s*
```

**EDIT:**

Here's some PHP code to give you an idea:

```
$str = 'CS#: A197789
Site Name: Made up name (F/A)
111E 1st Street=20
Somewhere, AZ 99999
Date and Time: Oct 1 2012 9:14AM
Event: CEE602 - TIMER TEST
Zone: E602 - Caller_ID: timer test
Site Phone 1: 
Site Phone 2:=20
System Description: NX 8 Caddx LF=0A=
=0D';

preg_match_all('/\s*([^:]+?)\s*:\s*(.*(?:\s*(?!.*:).*)*)\s*/m',
               $str,
               $matches,
               PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo "$match[1] => $match[2] <br>";
}
```

Outputs:

```
CS# => A197789
Site Name => Made up name (F/A)
111E 1st Street=20 Somewhere, AZ 99999 Date and Time => Oct 1 2012 9:14AM
Event => CEE602 - TIMER TEST
Zone => E602 - Caller_ID: timer test
Site Phone 1 =>
Site Phone 2 => =20
System Description => NX 8 Caddx LF=0A=
```

I leave it to you to try to solve the "Date and Time:" issue... (hint: 9:14AM)