# Regex matching multiple lines multiple times without matching date and time

Tags: php, regex

[Regex matching multiple lines multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552571/regex-matching-multiple-lines-multiple-times)

```
\s*([^:]+?)\s*:\s*(.*(?:\s*(?!.*:).*)*)\s*
```

This solution matches the date and time string.

How do I modify the above solution so that the date and time is included with the Description: header?

```
Name: John Doe

Age: 23

Primary Language: English

Description: This is a multiline
description field that I want 
to capture Fri, 02 Sep 2022 14:46:45 -0500

Country: Canada
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to exclude matching a comma in the first part before the colon:

```
^([^,:\n\r]+):(.*(?:\R(?![^,:\n\r]+:).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0F9AN/1)

Another option could be asserting that the next lines to match do not contain only a single colon:

```
^([^:\n\r]+):(.*(?:\R(?![^:\n\r]+:[^:\n\r]*$).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([^:\n\r]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than `:` or a newline
- `:` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\R` Match any unicode newline sequence
    - `(?![^:\n\r]+:[^:\n\r]*$)` Assert that the line does not contain a single occurrence of `:`
    - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to match all lines
- `)` Close group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bs1G8w/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/KiM8S).

Comment: The first solution worked great.

The second option returned two matches.  using php preg_match_all()

Array
(
    [0] => Name: John Doe

Age: 23

Primary Language: English

Description: This is a multiline
description field that I want 
to capture 
Fri, 02 Sep 2022 14:46:45 -0500

    [1] => Country: Canada
)

Comment: @MarcusCarey The second solution gets all the capture groups right? See https://regex101.com/r/Bs1G8w/1 and https://3v4l.org/KiM8S

Comment: Yes the demo work.  However, when I use it in a php script it returns 2 matches.  The first solution works in a script.  Thanks for the solution.